# Can't open an already existing project on Ecognition

Tags: ecognition

I worked on my home computer and saved some processing through an Ecognition project, but it looks like I just can't open it on my office computer and get the following error message (attached).

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: sounds like you have different versions? https://support.ecognition.com/hc/en-us/requests/new would be a good source for getting the right support.

Comment: Pictures of errors are not legible on all devices, and cannot be searched by others. Please remember to always include the error message in the body of the Question as text.